# How to change background color of a preferenceitem?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-settings

I've a preferenceactivity that load settings to my app from a xml resource
`addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.secondary_settings);`

I would like to change the items background color individually and programatically, how can i do it?

[image]

Comment: default color for background is #fafafa

Answer (score 0):

I did solve my problem thanks to myself and not to google.

From all the questions you get about `preference.getView` here and everywhere you kind of realizes that it doens't work for nothing and indeed in google's standard implementation of `Preference` it is kind of useless, it will return you a NEW view everytime you call it, while the old view (used on `PreferenceScreen`) keep untouched...
so unless you are building the whole PreferenceScreen out of android framework, this method is pretty useless... But I found a workaround

First of all it only works if you are using the `Compat` libs, it took me 1 day of work until to make it work because of that...

so your gradle must: `implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:$support_library_version"`
And your class must: `public class SecondarySettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat`

After migrating it, from wherever in your activity you want to get the PreferenceView do `((RecyclerView)findViewById(android.support.v7.preference.R.id.recycler_view).getChildAt(index);`

OBSERVATION, as it is a `RecycleView` it will have ZERO CHILDREN during `onCreate()` you must `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` or call your method from somewhere else